# Int Def declaration Java

Tags: java, android, int

whats the difference between these two declarations?

```
    public static final int a = 0;
    public static final int b = 1;
    public static final int c = 2;

    @IntDef({a, b, c})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface SomeIntDef {
    }
```

and

```
    @IntDef({a, b, c})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface SomeIntDef {
         int a = 0;
         int b = 1;
         int c = 2;
    }
```

I mean what is best practice or there any technical differences between these two declarations.

Comment: The former is defining the three possible values of the `int`; the latter is defining no possible values, but adding 3 fields (with no semantic meaning) with default values to the annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is some difference.

```
  public static final int a = 0;
  public static final int b = 1;
  public static final int c = 2;

  @IntDef({a, b, c})
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
  public @interface SomeIntDef {
  }
```

You are declaring static fields from anchor (parent) class of SomeIntDef. So this is how you reference it

```
YourParentClass.a
```

On the other hand,

```
  @IntDef({a, b, c})
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
  public @interface SomeIntDef {
     int a = 0;
     int b = 1;
     int c = 2;
  }
```

You are going to reference like

```
ParentClass.SomeIntDef.a
```

You can also write it as independent class. (Creating a new annotation in another .java file) which makes usage

```
SomeIntDef.a
```

These different usages are changing readability.

All of them are **acceptable**, but the choice is most meaningful one for your design.

Good luck

Emre